# How to add the files in $Home directory from blob of Azure cloud shell

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell, azure-cloud-shell

I am new to powershell. Writting code in azure cloud shell.
I want to add files in Azure cloud shell **$HOME** directory from blob storage.
How I can achieve this task?

Really appreciated for help.

To get script to add files into $home directory from azure blob storage in cloud shell

Later
Tried azcopy command
but getting error as:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qdcr.png)

Code what I tried
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZX7tQ.png)

Comment: @Chhhaya Can you share what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To get the script to add files into the $home directory from Azure blob storage in the cloud shell

To get the files from Azure blob storage to the $home directory, you can use the [Azcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10#run-azcopy) tool.

In my environment, Azure blob storage has five files as like below:

[image]

**Command:**

You can use the below command to get the multiple files to your home directory.

```
 azcopy cp "https://venkat123.blob.core.windows.net/test1/?<Your-sastoken>" "home/" --recursive=true
```

**Output:**

```
INFO: Scanning...
INFO: Any empty folders will not be processed, because the source and/or destination doesn't have full folder support
INFO: azcopy: A newer version 10.19.0 is available to download


Job 3cd8663a-58a1-xx has started
Log file is located at: /home/venkatesan/.azcopy/3cd8663a-xxx.log

0.0 %, 0 Done, 0 Failed, 5 Pending, 0 Skipped, 5 Total, 


Job 3cd8663a-58axxx5931561 summary
Elapsed Time (Minutes): 0.0334
Number of File Transfers: 5
Number of Folder Property Transfers: 0
Total Number of Transfers: 5
Number of Transfers Completed: 5
Number of Transfers Failed: 0
Number of Transfers Skipped: 0
TotalBytesTransferred: 115831
Final Job Status: Completed
```

[image]

Once you execute the above command, you can see the files in your home directory like below:

[image]

**Reference:**

[azcopy copy | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-copy?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json)

Comment: Thanks @Venkatesan, I added azcopy cp in my code, got sas token and append it in url, but I am getting error as-- failed to perform copy command due to error: cannot start job due to error: cannot list files due to reason -> 
github.com/Azure/azure-storage-blob-go/azblob.newStorageError, /usr/src/mariner/BUILD/azure-storage-azcopy-10.15.0/vendor/github.com/Azure/azure-storage-blob-go/azblob/zc_storage_error.go:42
(ServiceCode=AuthenticationFailed) 
Descr=403 Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature

Comment: @Chhaya Can you share a snippet of your error?

Comment: Sure. Added snippet of error in post

Comment: @Chhaya Add command also what you have tried by masking your sas-token.

Comment: Added code snippet

Comment: @Chhaya I tried with the same format in my environment https://i.imgur.com/XwjPWKF.png and it successfully gets the files from blob storage to the directory, here is my file https://i.imgur.com/Ry8Tk2g.png

Comment: @Chhaya Check with sas-token once token whether you are getting the correct output.

Comment: It worked. I went through your code, added subscriptionID and / in the end of Destination. Thank you so much.